# Splinter: DriverNotFoundError for zope.testbrowser

Tags: python, selenium, automation, zope, splinter

I am using Python Splinter to automate a website and to scrape data from it. When I use the default browser mode which is keeping blank in Browser() it opens firefox and completes the written task but, when I use the headless browser 'zope.testbrowser', I get the following error. What should I need to do here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysplinter.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = Browser('zope.testbrowser')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 62, in Browser
    raise DriverNotFoundError("No driver for %s" % driver_name)
splinter.exceptions.DriverNotFoundError: No driver for zope.testbrowser
```

Comment: I am seeing same for other browsers too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but will post anyway for the benefit of others.

I faced the same issue and my problem was that `mechanize` module was not installed.

**Fix**:

```
pip install mechanize
```

However, I faced another [issue](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/issues/531) after this.

#### Explanation

That's the line of code that is failing in `browser.py` of `splinter`, but due to `except: pass`, it is being silently ignored. If executed manually, the root of the problem can be observed:

```
>>> from splinter.driver.zopetestbrowser import ZopeTestBrowser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rustam/.virtualenvs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/zopetestbrowser.py", line 19, in <module>
    import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

Comment: This also means that zope.testbrowser can only be used with with python < 2.7 as mechanize is not available for python 3.x. However the documentation of zope.testbrowser says it would work for 3.x as well. Correct me if i'm wrong.